# Let $f(x) : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous function. Prove that there exist $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = x$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x) : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous function. Prove that there exist $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = x$.

I couldn't find any possible duplicate for this question. If you found please feel free to mark this obsolete and point me to that question.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not true as stated. Consider $f(x) = x+1$.

Comment: I'm going to make the bold claim that this one's not true.

Comment: Are you sure that is all the hypotheses you have? This is not true: $f(x) = 3$.

Comment: May we assume the function is surjective?

Comment: False. Consider $f(x) = x$ to see it is not always false.

Comment: I also feel that it should be "let :[0,1]→[0,1], "looks like some misprint in my text book. sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should read: " let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function..... ".

If yes, the consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then show that $g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1)  \le 0.$

Can you proceed ?